# NGiNX config to serve PHP app and Angular App on Subfolder

Tags: php, angular, linux, nginx, centos

I'm looking for a config example to configure my CentOS server to run both PHP and Angular apps on the same domain. PHP Works fine so far and both apps will run under a regular user (non root) account.

My root PHP app is at 
`public_html/`

My Angular App is at
`public_html/app`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Excellent question. It's not super verbose like most others... beautiful and succinct and made it really easy to read as it applies exactly with what I was trying to do as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People were hijacking this question and instead of providing answers they just posted complains about not providing sample code. I ended up finding the solution myself so I want to share it in case somebody is facing the same issues:

In my specific case I have both PHP and plain HTML (Angular) files serving in separate folders but under the same user/domain. The default config works correctly for PHP files but once I visited the folder `/app` where I have the Angular 8 app running I was getting a 502 error. To solve it I added the following to the default config file:

```
location /app/ {
    root /home/YOURUSER/public_html/app/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.htm /index;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
#Angular seems to have issues if you are not specific about CSS and JS files in headers
location ~ \.css {
    add_header Content-Type text/css;
}

location ~ \.js {
    add_header Content-Type application/x-javascript;
}
```

This seems to work correctly now.

Comment: Thank you for this, not knowing nginx it was very difficult to figure this out.